# How to link and use OpenCV headers?

Tags: c++, opencv

Right, I know this is a very stupid question, but I have no luck with w/e i'm trying to do.

I'm trying to use the objdetect.hpp header file, so I've included the folder C:\OpenCV2.1\include\opencv2\ aswell as C:\OpenCV2.1\include\opencv and a whole bunch of other libraries and dlls when I was following the instructions on http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B_VS2010

But the openCV version in that tutorial were outdated and doesn't even have the objdetect.hpp file. So I went to download the latest one (OpenCV 2.4.0), but now when I complie it, it gives me an error C1083: Cannot open include file: "opencv2/core/core.hpp" No such file directory.

Am I suppost to put all the OpenCV folders/files in the same directory as my C++ project? Or how do I fix it? I've tried putting it in the same place as my C++ project, but when I do a `#include "../"` the folder doesn't appear.

Again, I know this is a stupid question, but please help.

Let me know if anyone require more info coz I'm not too sure whatelse to put.

Thanks

Comment: You have to tell Visual Studio all the paths you are going to use. OpenCV. For libs you have to add the path OpenCV\bin\lib. For headers you have to add OpenCV\build\include. If you need to incolude a header do something like this:  #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

Comment: My OpenCV folder doesn't even have a bin folder :(. It has a build folder and many others, but not a bin... :S

Comment: the important is the include folder, so VS can find ther headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to manage changing directories for include files is with the compiler options. Im better at linux and g++, where you would just specify different include path locations with `-I` attributes.

Its generally considered bad practice to use relative and absolute paths in the `#include` statements. Module paths are ok `#include <sys/time.h>`, where `sys` could be considered the module. Include the file with just its name and possibly the module, then handle the location with the compiler options.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Forgot to tell you that the error is occuring IN the objdetect.hpp file, so wouldn't it be kind of bad to change source code that you didn't wrote yourself? Is there another way around it?

Comment: @Danny, of course, if the code comes that way, then you should probably leave it. You should install it in a place that makes sense on your system, then figure out the paths and set those on the compiler options.

Comment: I installed it in the C:\ drive and I have included the C:\OpenCV2.1\include\opencv2 in the included directory as stated above, but the problem is that it can't find other folders for it :(