# Using OpenCV 2.4.0 in a Visual Studio 2010 project

Tags: c++, opencv

I have asked a similar question on [How to link and use OpenCV headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818437/how-to-link-and-use-opencv-headers), but no luck so far. So I decided to ask a new, more specific question.

What OpenCV-specific folders or files do I need to include in my C++ project -- and how I might include them? I have installed OpenCV 2.4.0 on my C:\ drive. I've looked at the tutorials in openCV's website, but they are for an older version (OpenCV 2.1) and refer to non-existent files like objdetect.hpp (for example).

Comment: This is up-to-date: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windows-installation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to

Add these to your stdafx.h

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>        // cv::Mat etc, always need this
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>  // all the image processing functions
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>  // Display and file I/O
```

Assuming you have set OPENCV_DIR to the place you put opencv eg. `OPENCV_DIR=c:\opencv2.4\opencv`

Then set the VC++ directories in project settings to 
Include add `$(OPENCV_DIR)\include` and to Library add `$(OPENCV_DIR)\lib`

Then in the "linker Input" add opencv_core240.lib (opencv_core240D.lib for debug) opencv_imgproc240.lib and opencv_highgui240.lib etc

Comment: The first thing I think of here is "why don't the sub-libraries always include core?"  But that's something more suited for the OpenCV website.

Comment: @Kevin - you can always make a "opencv.hpp" which includes all the others, but that's what a precompiled header does anyway. The number of libraries is unfortunately increasing since they have to separate out functions that are patented in some countries - although there will be a single opencv_global.lib for eg. phones where it's harder to have lots of libs

Comment: I don't mean "include everything always" I mean that if you always need to include this one header for the others to work, why aren't those others including it, thus saving one more line the user doesn't need in their file?  Something tells me they are, and the extra include is superfluous, but I haven't used this library before, and that's just the first thing that occurred to me from looking at your snippet.  If I'm just interpreting your snippet wrong, then forgive me.

Comment: @kevin - every other lib would have to include core since you might use imgproc but not highgui or vv. The 'C/C++' way is to do this at the program level rather than includes chaining other includes. The C++ STL is even worse, you have to know the inheritence tree to get the includes for a simple console print

Answer (score 1):

The folder structure of OpenCV has changed in 2.4, therefore you should use other folder than mentioned in the tutorial:

- Point `OPENCV_DIR` to the build-directory (e.g. `C:\opencv\build`), NOT the platform-specific dir.
- The Path-Variable must point to your platform-specific bin-directory (e.g. `%OPENCV_DIR%\x86\vc10\bin`)...
- ...same for the Linker properties (e.g. `$(OPENCV_DIR)\x86\vc10\lib`)