# Why Symbol 'CV_8UC3' could not be resolved in Eclipse OS X?

Tags: eclipse, opencv

I'm getting Symbol 'CV_8UC3' could not be resolved error and can't build the project.

```
cv::Mat ImgBuf(yRes,xRes,CV_8UC3,(unsigned char*) g_Img);
```

This includes have been included without any error.

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
```

Comment: I believe that the error doesn't have anything to do with include files but libraries you linked. See if you are linking all necessary libraries.

Comment: I have linked these ones : [libs image](http://i037.radikal.ru/1210/c0/be7c9d9496f5.jpg)

Comment: I think I have all the needed linked. What's wrong ?

Comment: Is that the only OpenCv lib folder you are adding? The path should be something like OpenCV/lib and not OpenCV/3rdparty/lib

Comment: By default OpenCV is installed to /opt/local/ according to MacPorts conventions. The opencv_xxxx utilities are located in /opt/local/bin/, the dynamic libraries in /opt/local/lib/ and the header files in /opt/local/include/opencv/.

To use the libraries, include the required files with standard includes.

I don't know about the path you say. I can't find opencv/lib...

Comment: You are right, my bad, forgot you are on a Mac. This is very strange. It is very far fetched but try moving /opt/local/lib/ (or where the OpenCV libs are) before the ...OpenCV/3rdparty/lib on Library search paths..

Comment: Not solved yet. I've removed the /opt/local/share/OpenCV/3rdparty as it doesn't exist on my system. So /opt/local/lib/  is first and no result...

Comment: however I still can build and run . Strange...

Comment: Someone knows why this happens? 
[image](http://habrastorage.org/storage2/e75/e02/a02/e75e02a024673fa91668b7ff2361efd5.png)
The program compiles and runs successfully. But the red errors in code are annoying me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using OpenCV 2.4.0 in a Visual studio 2010 project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831088/using-opencv-2-4-0-in-a-visual-studio-2010-project)